# Firebase Dynamic Hosting Rewrite the home page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase dynamic hosting and would like the home page on my website (https://website.com) to redirect to a cloud function while all other urls are directed to a React app.

I have tried this in Firebase.json. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
"rewrites": [
  { "source": "/", "function": "app"},
  { "source": "**", "function": "/index.html"}
]
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: have you tried { "source": "", "function": "app"}

Answer (score 4):

When you hit your website home page, firebase always tries to find the "index.html" file in your public directory. If it is found, your rewrite "is not executed". To avoid this, remove your "index.html" file (or just rename it), and the first rewrite will start working.

About the second rewrite, if you are trying to return a file of your public directory, the key of that object needs to be "destination", instead of "function".

Let's say that you rename your "index.html" file to "myApp.html". Your firebase.json file would be:

```
"rewrites": [
  { "source": "/", "function": "app"},
  { "source": "**", "destination": "/myApp.html"}
]
```

Comment: Thats so right Jesus... Wish I found your answer before I figured it out myself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519531/how-to-change-firebase-homepage-destination/53520119#53520119

Comment: WOW! Is this for real? The docs doesn't mention that at all. I've been struggling with this for the last 24 hours.

Comment: I had this open issue about this and they responded. It is infact the intended behavior for the Hosting response priorities. Rewrities have lower priority than static files (and homepage === index.html): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1785